# Unique input fields based on specific event type ID's

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I've been tasked with creating a physical event logging system, where an employee will create an event based on a physical event that occurred purely for logging purposes. For example, say they answer the phone - they must then create a "Phone" event and fill in who called, why, and when.

Each `event` will have the same input fields accessible to enter, **however** some of them require additional input fields that are only accessible to specific `event_types`.

Here's a snippet of the schema:

```
table: event_types

| column | type    |
|--------|---------|
| id     | integer |
| name   | varchar |


table: events    

| column        | type     |
|---------------|----------|
| id            | integer  |
| report_id     | integer  |
| user_id       | integer  |
| event_type_id | integer  |
| date          | datetime |
| details       | text     |
| locations     | json     |
| people        | json     |
| data          | json     |
```

Basically, the `event_type_id` can be one of 50+ event types. Only 15 of them will require unique fields. These event types are static when the app is installed (they are seeded into the DB), and users won't be creating them in the app itself.

The `locations`, `people` and `date` field will be available inputs on every event. My initial thoughts was to have a `data` `json` field to store additional input field data.

However, I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle unique input fields depending on specific `event_type_id`'s. I'm also not sure how I'll handle validating these unique fields based on the `event_type_id`.

Would it be best to hard-code `event_type_id`'s and then assign validation rules depending on which `event_type_id` an event is created with? I'm also wondering how to handle this when rendering the form view to load in the additional input fields.

I've also thought about storing the validation rules and the view name inside the `event_types` table, but I thought doing so may be bad practice since I'd need to update the `event_type` record in the database anytime I want to add another field.

I'm really hoping for some advice from anyone who's had to implement handling unique fields within their database - I'm really not sure how to handle this properly... Thanks so much for your time!

**EDIT:** I've went with a hybrid - a very limited version of the Entity-Value-Model and json data fields. I'll be posting my complete implementation in the coming days for others in case it helps anyone.

Comment: The answer is 'no one knows'. You're asking the right kind of questions though, but I'd be tempted to go with your instincts and be prepared to review and revise it in due course.

Comment: Lets say you have an event which has metadata like why did they speak about, further actions etc etc. Another event might have some other metadata. Is the application in need to select/filter the records based on the metadata. Or if this is just for logging purpose, why not store them into serialised array and use larave's array casting?

Comment: May be the most common fields like name of the person, location etc you can store separately to filter later. But the other detailed metadata can be serialised if it's a secondary information.

Comment: Any complex validations should be done in your front-end/Business logic. DB is a place to store nothing more. You can use SP for your INSERT, DELETE actions which takes care of uniqueness depend on your business logic.

Comment: @MihirBhende That was my initial plan. The additional data is going to be shown when viewing the event, so other users know that a certain task was done for a certain event. The validation and view rendering for the extra dynamic fields is where I'm worried about its implementation, as I'm thinking I might be hitting a potential brick wall down the line after I implement what I have currently.

Comment: I think the validation can be handled. I currently have a project where I have user actions tracked and it has huge table with 250000+ records. I can say it was good to have secondary metadata in single column than having different columns to store each field separately :)